# Epic Games- Fortnite download Cancelled

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

What will happen if the download is canceled in between and continued the next day... Will it affect the files downloaded and cause some lagging in the game after download?

Comment: How you complete the update isn't going to cause lagging in game, no. I can't give a definitive answer but I'd guess there may be some wasted download if there was a game update overnight, otherwise it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that the same files will be downloaded and there will be no difference in performance just because of a paused download.